# Firebreath - NPAPI - getElementsByName not working

Tags: javascript, npapi, firebreath

I'm trying to call javascript native method `getElementsByName` to retrieve the list of all elements with the same name (name="").

Here is the code I'm using with Internet Explorer:

```
std::vector<FB::JSObjectPtr> nameList = DOMdoc->callMethod<std::vector<FB::JSObjectPtr> >("getElementsByName", FB::variant_list_of("name1");
```

No result is returned. By executing directly the method in javascript, I have the right number of items:

```
document.getElementsByName("name1")
```

I also tried to use directly the getElementById which works but returns only one element:

```
DOMdoc->getElementById("name1")->getJSObject();
```

Unfortunately I need to retrieve the list of elements for a radiobutton for exemple:

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="value1">Radio 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="value2">Radio 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="value3">Radio 3<br/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Just tried with getElementsByTagName without more success:

```
nameList = DOMdoc->callMethod<std::vector<FB::JSObjectPtr> >("getElementsByTagName", FB::variant_list_of("name1"));
```

Comment: You don't have elements in code example `with name="name"`

Comment: Post updated. Of course the name was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which browser you're using; I'm guessing you're probably using IE. If not this may not help.

There are some methods like that that can't be called directly from a plugin in IE, you have to use the correct interface.  That's why there is a [special method on FB::DOM::Element](http://www.firebreath.org/x/iAJq) for calling that method.

Try something like:

```
std::vector<FB::DOM::ElementPtr> nameList = DOMdoc->getElementsByTagName("name1");
```

I'm assuming, though you didn't specify, that you got DOMdoc by calling `m_host->getDOMDocument()`

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer taxilian. Unfortunately with getElementsByTagName it's not working neither. You're right, I'm using IE. I've updated my first post. Do you have another idea for me?